# Interval in Django template

Tags: django, time, django-templates, formatting, intervals

I have an interval type field that contains hours and minutes in this format: "28:00".
But in my template, it is translated to "1 day, 4:00:00"
How can I keep this "28:00" in my template?

**My template:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead align="center">
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">User</th>
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Week number</th>
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Total H</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for tp in resume_h %}
        <tr  scope="row">
            <td class="text-center col-md-1">{{ tp.user_name  }}</td>
            <td class="text-center col-md-1">{{ tp.num_semaine }}</td>>
            <td class="text-center col-md-1">{{ tp.hours_total|linebreaksbr }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My model:**

```
class hours(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    num_semaine = models.IntegerField(("No:"),blank=True, null=True)    
    hours_total = models.TimeField(("H"),blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)
```

Thank you

Comment: This actually already exists: a `DurationField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield It even has some nice "humanization" features to display it like we humans would specify intervals (like "5 minutes ago").

Comment: I added 'django.contrib.humanize', in my settings and I added models.DurationField () in my model but I still do not get the desired result.